# Angularjs authentication redirect issue

Tags: angularjs, authentication, location

I am having an app that every page except login requires authentication. I do this by checking the  $stateChangeStart and then redirecting to /login when token is not set. on initial app load this works fine, but at login screen if i type another "restricted" url. It does the check, changes the url, but still loads the restricted page. What am I missing here?

//app.run:

```
 app.lazy = $couchPotato;
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toStateParams) {
        console.log("state changed to "+toState.name);
        console.log(toState);
        Authentication.validateLogin(toState, toStateParams);
    });
```

Authentication.validateLogin:

```
validateLogin:function(toState, toStateParams){
        $rootScope.toState = toState;
        $rootScope.toStateParams = toStateParams;
        if ($localStorage.token == null) {
             console.error("Not Authenticated!");
             $location.url('/login');
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to redirect using `$window.location.href` ?

Comment: Doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your using angular-ui, so I'm not exactly sure what advantages that has over using 'basic' angular, but I wrote this to handle validating a token when the route changes.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', 'authService',
    function ($rootScope, authService) {
        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, next, current) {
            if (next && next.$$route && authService.isAuthenticated()) {
                authService.validate();
                $rootScope.appTitle = next.$$route.title;
            }
        });
    }]);
```

The $routeChangeSuccess handles navigation to routes *after* the controller has loaded (very important for objects that load when the page loads when validation is confirmed), and then validates them.

This also performs 2 checks in that it checks if the token in local storage exists and is formed correctly, and if it is, send it back to the server to confirm that.

I also found that I had to use the $locationChangeStart to handle page refresh, to re-validate when someone tries to refresh the page.

The validateLogin solution:

```
validateLogin:function(toState, toStateParams){
  if(toState.access){
        if(toState.access.loginRequired){
               if ($localStorage.token == null) {
                   $state.go('login');
               }
         }
  }
```

Comment: Wow, this is great to know. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Comment: What does your route config look like?  Do you have any additional properties set on your routes that would conflict with something?

Comment: yeah, I have: urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

Comment: I am passing some data, but, that was after the issue came up.

Comment: Are you able to create a Plunker or something to replicate the issue?

Comment: I figured it out. I want you to edit your answer and include my answer so I can give you credit. For some reason, probably a bug, but it render the page at the same time. Once I used ui-routers $state.go() and your solution it worked!

Comment: That makes sense.  In addition to the $locationChangeStart I mentioned earlier, I did have to include a $route.reload.  I added it, look good?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the validateLogin:

```
validateLogin:function(toState, toStateParams){
      if(toState.access){
            if(toState.access.loginRequired){
                   if ($localStorage.token == null) {
                       $state.go('login');
                   }
             }
      }
}
```